# error 404 (Not Found) when trying to get local JSON file with AJAX method on django project

Tags: json, django, ajax

I'm trying to access my database from a JS file. In order to do so I serialized all my models objects into local JSON files and now I'm trying to read this files with the AJAX method (which I've never tried before), but it's failing to find them.

My directories look something like this:

```
/RecipeSite
  (...)
  /reading
  /writing
    (...)
    /static/writing/
             /css
             /scss
             /js
               forms.js
             /json
               test.json
  (...)
```

---

my setting.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

(...)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, STATIC_URL),
    os.path.join("RecipeSite", "static"),
)

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'RecipeSite-home'
```

---

this are my RecipeSite/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from users import views as users_views


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('reading.urls')),
    path('new_recipe/', include('writing.urls')),
    re_path(r'^Register/$', users_views.register, name='register'),
    re_path(r'^Login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'), name='login'),
    re_path(r'^Logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),
]

django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

---

my reading/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.urls import include, path, re_path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='home_page/', permanent=True)),
    path('home_page/', views.index, name='RecipeSite-home'),
    re_path(r'(?P<r_Name>[\w.@+-]+)/(?P<r_Id>\d+)', views.about, name='recipe'),
]
```

---

my writing/urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.writing, name='writing'),
]
```

---

In my writing/js/forms.js I have this code:

```
(...)
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "/test.json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
(...)
```

but when I run it, the console shows GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/test.json 404 (Not Found)

Comment: show your urls please

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

**urls.py**

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

    path( "test.json",
        TemplateView.as_view(template_name="static/writing/test.json", content_type="application/json")),
```

However, during production, Django [does not serve static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-dedicated-server), that will be the work of your web server which should,and is able to, serve the json file.

Comment: I am using the AJAX method because I want to access my database without having to reload the page, loading a whole template will not work for me

Comment: The view will still return the json you require but in production, your web server e.g Nginx and Apache can better serve the file. You might also need to add `static` to `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in settings if you decide to go the django way